# Object value is null after deserialization (Xamarin with SQLite)

Tags: sqlite, xamarin, deserialization, textblob

for an internship project I'm developping an app with Xamarin that will allow users to scan barcodes and create sheets of labels and purchases.

To prevent the scanned codes from being lost in case of crash etc, I've implemented SQLite to create a local backup that we could restore.

The structure is as follows : a `ListOfLabelLines` contains several `LabelLine` which each contain a `Product` and different other informations (such as packaging, quantity etc).

ListOfLabelLines.cs :

```
    [Table("ListOfLabelLines")] // Indique le nom de la table qui sera générée par SQLite
    public class ListOfLabelLines : BaseItem
    {
        private string _name { get; set; }
        [TextBlob("LabelLinesBlob")]
        public ObservableCollection<LabelLine> lines { get; set; }
        [TextBlob("ListBlob")]
        public List<String> TestList { get; set; }

        public string LabelLinesBlob { get; set; } // serialized LabelLines
        public string ListBlob { get; set; } // serialized TestList


        public ListOfLabelLines()
        {

        }

        public ListOfLabelLines(string name)
        {
            this._name = name;
            lines = new ObservableCollection<LabelLine>();
            TestList = new List<String>();
            TestList.Add("Test1");
            TestList.Add("Test2");
        }

        public string Name
        {
            get { return _name; }
            set
            {
                _name = value;
            }
        }
    }

}
```

These objects `ListOfLabelLines` contain an `ObservableCollection<LabelLine>` which I'm serializing by using the TextBlob property from SQLite-net-extensions.

However, when I retrieve the `ListOfLabelLines` I've stored, the ObservableCollection appears as null :

[Example of null collections](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LRmPw.png)

Here are the methods I use to store the objects in SQlite :

```
        public void SaveListOfLabelLines(ListOfLabelLines ShelfLabelInstance)
        {
            var query = from label in database.Table<ListOfLabelLines>()
                        where label.Name == ShelfLabelInstance.Name
                        select label;
            var res = query.FirstOrDefault();
            if (res != null)
            {
                database.UpdateWithChildren(ShelfLabelInstance);
                Console.WriteLine("Label " + ShelfLabelInstance.Name + " updated");
            }
            else
            {
                database.InsertWithChildren(ShelfLabelInstance);
                Console.WriteLine("Label " + ShelfLabelInstance.Name + " created");
            }
        }
```

and to retrieve them :

```
        public void CheckProductsInLabelLine(string n)
        {
            var query = from LOLL in database.Table<ListOfLabelLines>()
                        where LOLL.Name == n
                        select LOLL;
            ListOfLabelLines res = query.FirstOrDefault();
```

The string property linked to the TextBlob, however, contains the JSON object I need.

I thought the ObservableCollection would be obtainable when getting the object in DB since TextBlob is supposed to serialize AND deserialize.

Could anybody help ?

Thanks a lot !

Comment: Could you clarify which variable corresponds to the JSON object you stored in SQLite for me and what its relation to the ObservableCollection<LabelLine> is?

Comment: Hi, sure ! What I'm trying to do is save the ObservableCollection<LabelLine> in SQLite. Since I cannot store it as it is, I'm using TextBlob to store it as a string. It seems like it's stored correctly, because the string variable LabelLinesBlob contains a JSON object built from the ObservableCollection. The issue is when I go get the ObservableCollection in DB and try to restore it ; then it is displayed as null, as you can see in my screenshot.
Thanks for your help and if anything is still unclear don't hesitate to let me know !

Comment: are you sure you are storing and retrieving Name/_name as in ShelfLabelInstance.Name correctly? Has the console ever printed the "Label ...updated" message?

Comment: are you sure you are storing and retrieving Name/_name as in ShelfLabelInstance.Name correctly? Has the console ever printed the "Label ...updated" message? As in maybe you need to check that LOLL.Name == n is working and returning a valid query.

Comment: Which SQLite nuget package do you have right now

Comment: @user0xF22F7 : Yes, the name works properly and the Console.WriteLine displays with no issue.

Comment: @G.hakim I am using sqlite-net-pcl 1.5.231 (latest stable release) and SQLiteNetExtensions 2.1.0 (same).